# Just reload page content not header or footer? - I need to learn AJAX with PHP & jQuery.

Tags: php, ajax

I have deigned a website and i am wanting the header and footer to stay on the page and not refresh when a page navigation link is selected on the navigation bar i just want the content to refresh.

I have header.php which contains the header and footer.php which contains the footer

at the top of each page i have `<?php include("header.php"); ?>`
and at the bottom i have `<?php include("footer.php"); ?>`

these contain div tags
named appropriately and my content has its own div tag called content

i have searched the internet and heard ajax could be used but nothing is coming up to how to do this, could anyone suggest any code to help or point me in the right direction

Thanks

Jack

Comment: I very much doubt that "nothing is coming up" when you search for AJAX. There are loads and loads of tutorials.

Comment: Try to learn ajax first http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could learn it really quickly by using these video tutorials.
Alex makes it really simple to understand and uses PHP & jQuery to walk you through Step by Step on AJAX and everything else that goes with it.

[101 - AJAX Load](http://thenewboston.org/watch.php?cat=32&number=101)
[102 - AJAX Send Data](http://thenewboston.org/watch.php?cat=32&number=102)
[103 - AJAX Callback Handlers](http://thenewboston.org/watch.php?cat=32&number=103)
[104 - Changing AJAX data type](http://thenewboston.org/watch.php?cat=32&number=104)
[105 - AJAX Status Codes](http://thenewboston.org/watch.php?cat=32&number=105)

You could complete the entire 200 Part Series here to become an expert in jQuery!
[Entire 200 Part Video Tutorial on jQuery](http://thenewboston.org/list.php?cat=32)

Comment: The website you suggested is amazing! wish i had this weeks ago! going to use it to learn the coding languages I'm wanting to know

Comment: Yup, check out his channel on youtube: http://www.youtube.com/user/thenewboston and watch the videos there, if you get stuck you can use youtube comments to see how other people resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of resources out there for learning AJAX out there. @Hary suggested w3schools and I'd second that.

This site has a good example of a site that you can navigate using AJAX.

http://javascriptsource.com/ajax/ajax-navigation.html

I'd suggest having a look at both and then coming back with some code to show if you're still stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally use jQuery '.get' as its a lot less code and It's easier to manipulate the data imo